# Searview Android

Tags: java, android, searchview

I'm Currently developing an app that using searchview and until now i'm a bit stuck. i got everything's working unless make the searchview fill entire space between back arrow and searchview.

I'm now trying to create an expandable search that looks like the one in the pic below
[image]

and this is what i've got so far

```
    <style name="AppSearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView">
      <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/ic_search</item>

      <item name="queryBackground">@null</item>

      <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>

      <item name="queryHint">@string/search_hint</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

is that possible to do it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the following attributes in your search menu item if not add it

`app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"`